# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед «где»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Она даже не спрашивает(,) где ты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед "где" нужна: **Она даже не спрашивает, где ты.**

Придаточное предложение отделяется от главного запятой или выделяется запятыми с двух сторон, если находится внутри главного предложения.
Запятой отделяются также неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные предложения, например: *Садитесь, где свободно; Встретимся, знаете где.*

Спросил, где ты, и я ему сказала, что тебя сейчас исключают из партии, объяснила за что. [Эдуард Розенталь. Отец // «Вестник США», 2003.10.15]
Теперь темно, не видал я тебя, не знаю, где ты! [А. К. Толстой. Князь Серебряный (1861-1863)]
Я все-таки пишу тебе, хотя не знаю, где ты. [В. Ф. Панова. Кружилиха. Роман (1947)]

[Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, ведь здесь у нас полноценное придаточное.